# Mavericks Calendar sync with Google seems entirely broken?

Tags: data-synchronization, calendar, macos, google-calendar

In a long drawn out story that started with trying to implement CardDAV (I'd like to store my contacts on google if possible), I removed my google account from `Internet Accounts`, which had existed there from Mountain Lion, and was working perfectly fine for Calendar.app and Messages.app.

Upon trying to re-add the Google account and have it sync my calendars, It's telling me that it cant do it anymore. I'm using two-factor google authentication, and I provide the setup with a generated, app specific password. Contacts and Messages click instantly, but Calendars sits spinning. It eventually informs me that:

> **A secure connection couldn't be established**
>
> Click "Continue" to continue creating the account. 
>   You can edit the account later in Calendar 
>   preferences if necessary
>
> *Cancel* **Continue**

Console informs me that:

```
28/10/2013 2:26:38.652 am com.apple.internetaccounts[13796]: [com.apple.calendar.iaplugin.log.CalInternetAccountsPlugin] [Autodiscovery error: [Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo=0x7fbbc50f0550 {NSUnderlyingError=0x7fbbc5629870 "The request timed out.", NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://user%40gmail.com@google.com:8443/principals/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://user%40gmail.com@google.com:8443/principals/, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}].]
```

Continue will just repeat this loop indefinitely.

I've done some digging and found these resources, although evidently they did not work for me:

- http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/calendar/7XZkRZzo10I/5oo7RReNhrAJ
- https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/caldav/v2/guide#new_endpoint

It seems that the endpoint is no longer valid? Multiple attempts to create a CalDav account in Advanced mode attempting all flavours and variations bore no fruit.

How can I get this working again?

Comment: Did you get this working?

Comment: See the answer below :)

Comment: Well, I had seen it, I just wondered if it had continued to work. I was having some unrelated issues last night, which is when I came upon your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reattempted the standard google process today, and it failed on ical (no account) but going to internet accounts and attempting to enable calendar worked.

I can only deduce some form of google services were down or misconfigured in this period.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me:

1. Open Calendar.app
2. Open Preferences (⌘+,)
3. Click Accounts tab
4. Click plus button (+) to add an account
5. Select "Add CalDAV Account..."
6. Click Continue
7. Select "Account Type" Manual
8. Username is your **full email address** "yourname@gmail.com"
9. Password is your password (or application specific password if you use 2 factor auth)
10. Server Address is "https://www.google.com"

Notes:

1. Don't forget the "@gmail.com" on your gmail address! You can also use your own domain name if a Google Apps user
2. The "https://" on the Server Address field is critical. Without this you will get an error about not being able to establish a secure connection (https uses SSL where http doesn't).

Comment: This solution does not work as of today. I created an application-specific password for just my calendar, followed these steps precisely, and I receive the message "Unable to verify account name or password"